# Cannot formulate correctly my repository method for fetching a list of objects that are existing in another object

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, repository

This is the first time I've been working with Springboot and JPA and I am struggling to write a repository method.

I have two objects:

```
public class ObjectA{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "objectA_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(length=40, unique=true, nullable = false)
    private String label;
}
```

and

```
public class ObjectB{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="objectB_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(length = 100, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String label;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="refObjectA_id", nullable = false)
    private List<ObjectA> ObjectAs;
}
```

Now, I would like to have a repository method to fetch the objects A if only at least one object B is "linked" to it. Since I don't know how to do so, I wrote a MySQL query that I tested and worked perfectly but I was wondering if there was a way to do it without specifying the query.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM objectA
WHERE objectA_id IN 
(SELECT objectAs_id FROM objectB_objectAs)
```

objectB_objectAs is the join table between the two objects.

If anyone has an idea on how to do such a thing, I would be glad to hear about that :)

Thank you for reading !

Answer (score 0):

Well, to begin with, there should not be a "join table" for this many-to-one relationship, a record from table A should simply reference an ID from table B.

A "join table" is only necessary in the case of a many-to-many relationship, if each object could be linked to many of the other object.

Your SQL query would then be :

```sql
SELECT *
FROM objectA
WHERE objectA.objectB_id is not null
```

Then writing it in JPQL is trivial

UPDATE :

Since the true relationship seems to be a "many-to-many" and not a "many-to-one" (one B can have multiple As but one A can also be linked to multiple B), here is how the SQL query should look :

```sql
SELECT *
FROM objectA A
LEFT JOIN objectA_objectB AB ON AB.objectA_ID = A.ID
WHERE AB.objectB_ID is not null
```

And "LEFT JOIN" do exist in JPQL : https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-types

Comment: I may have expressed my needs incorrectly. To make it clear, I simplified my objects but I may have over simplified them. I, indeed, have a many to many relation between these objects, hence why I have a join table. I'm sorry for the confusion

Comment: You should edit your question then. ManyToMany can not be described with a "@JoinColumn" only, it needs a "@JoinTable", see : https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many